# Rubygem: How to load information of a yaml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, constants

My gem generates the following file into *config/my_gem.yml*:

```
test: true
```

Now I want to **load the value** of test into my gems module to be able to call:

```
MyGem.test
=> true
```

---

**That was my attempt:**

In the Rails App - *config/initializers/my_gem.rb:*

```
CONFIG_PATH = "#{Rails.root}/config/my_gem.yml"
MY_GEM = YAML.load_file(CONFIG_PATH)[Rails.env]
```

In the gem - *lib/my_gem.rb:*

```
def self.test
    ::MY_GEM[:test]
end
```

But I get an exception because `MY_GEM` does not get recognized as a constant (in *lib/my_gem.rb*)

> c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/my_gem-0.1.0/lib/my_gem.rb:11:in `test': uninitialized constant MY_GEM (NameError)

Comment: Don't call your gem "gem" – this is confusing. Seriously, don't. The gem will get loaded before the Rails app is initialized. Try and read the config file from inside the gem.

Comment: @Raffael Ok, I am going to change that. Just called it that way for presenting purposes

Comment: Sorry if I was being a bit dogmatic. This really is much better though :D

Comment: @Raffael How would you access the file from within the gem? I mean, I cannot call `Rails.root` to get the path to the `config` directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to load app yaml files by doing this in your gem:

```
YAML.load_file('config/my_gem.yml')
```

This requires that the working directory is the root of your Rails application – which is the case when you invoke the rails command while in that directory.

Comment: It can be so easy :) No need for `Rails.root` - yay!

Answer (score 1):

Two things to note here. The first is that your `initializer` gets called *after* the gem itself is loaded, but before Rails is operational. This is provided as an opportunity to do any last-minute configuration. If the gem is expecting the initializer to run first it's in for a rude awakening.

The second is that YAML like that will have string keys, so even if your constant was defined, `ABCDEFG[:test]` would be `nil`. You must reference it with a string key, or use `symbolize_keys` on the data, recursively.

Comment: Ok, so I need to parse the `yml` file inside my gem. How can I get the correct path to the config directory of the app the gem is being used in?

Comment: If you don't know where that file is going to be you need to defer loading it until your  initializer fires.